# Passing a textbox value to another textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, globalization

I have given a default value "2.5" for a textbox called "diff_Box" and then in order to check something in another purpose, I took this value and paste it into another textbox called "textbox5". But in textbox5 it is displayed as 25. I know it is a very common issue but I can not solve it somehow. I have tried sofar;

```
double diff;

diff = Double.parse(diff_Box.Text);
diff = Convert.ToDouble(diff_Box.Text);



textBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(diff);
textBox5.Text = diff.ToString("F2");
textBox5.Text = ToString.parse(diff);
```

but I am encountering all the time the same problem

thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you converting it? have I missed something? Surely textBox5.Text = diff_Box.Text will work?

Comment: You should use the textBox only for input / output; not as a container for the actual value. 
Store the value in a local variable `Double _diff;` and use it for both text boxes.

Comment: @Aphelion I disagree. Why create another variable to store what the textbox already does.

Comment: @Doomsknight because the textbox does not actually contains the value, but a `string` representation.

Comment: First I have checked the value which is assigned to diff in IntelliTrace then I have created another textbox "textbox5" in order to check if diff is assigned the right value which is 2.5 but in textbox5 and also in IntelliTrace diff is 25 but diff_box value is 2.5. So diff = Convert.ToDouble(textbox5.text) passes the value 2.5 somehow as 25

Comment: So my aim is not storing double diff in textboxes but just checking if it is assigned the right value 2.5. I hope I have expressed my problem correctly this time.

Comment: Do you have the initial textbox value of 2.5 set with code or through VS/IDE?

Comment: @Bali C: in form1.Designer.cs; I have written  this.diff_box.Text = "2.5"; And I guess you are pointing the right way this is the only possibility why it does not pass the value as intended. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Any Special reason for using diff.ToString("F2");.?

Comment: @mrtcn The only thing I can think of is that you are using quotes when you set it, so it is a string to start with. In which case the conversion to a double and back to a string wouldn't be necessary, what happens if you try and assign it the value of the textbox, without the conversion, just a string?

Comment: try without F2 in ToString();

Comment: @Bali C: I have exchanged it with   textBox5.Text = diff_box.Text; and now textbox5 displays 2.5 But for me important thing is double diff. I can not assign the value 2.5 to diff as you see at the last image the value of diff is 25 not 2.5

Comment: @MMK I have tried it but does not bring anything. The same problem. diff_box holds the right value 2.5 but when I try: diff = Convert.ToDouble(diff_box.Text); diff is assigned as 25.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are **not** using the format used by your system UI culture. You actually are using the `InvariantCulture` on your GUI.

You use a `.` in the textbox.  I assume your current UI culture uses `,`. Therefore it sees no digits after the `.` and results in `25.0` instead of `2.5`.

This line will convert back using the InvariantCulture instead of the system UI culture:

```
double diff = Double.Parse(diff_Box.text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

---

The better approach however is to use a private `Double _diff` and just convert it to the required culture for display on the form. Second, you should expect the users to use the UI culture for data-entry.

Comment: Where did you see it? I can not see any comma in the code. I have used point all the time.

Comment: But if you want, You can edit your answer as;
double diff = Double.Parse(diff_box.text,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Because otherwise it does not work.